# Add Quip Calendar entries via API

Tags: quip, liveapps

Is there a way to add a new entry to a live quip calendar using an API? I have not found an API that exposed the calendar object inside a live quip document, but maybe it is undocumented.

Answer (score 0):

**You cannot do this with the calendar live app today **. You can edit a Table/sheet as it has individual row and column structure via API's (Edit document)